# How do I access the first value in the list?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a knee. And there are certain values ​​in this array. How do I access '**TopLink**'?

```
const MultiLinkArray = [
  {
    'TopLink': [
      {
        'name': 'BottomLink1',
        'to':'/bottomlink1'
      },
      {
        'name': 'BottomLink2',
        'to':'/bottomlink2'
      },
      {
        'name': 'BottomLink3',
        'to':'/bottomlink3'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**The output I want:** TopLink

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you elaborate? You want to access `TopLink` but you want to output `TopLink` also? You just want the key as a string or what?

Comment: `TopLink` as a `array` or `TopLink` as a `string`?
please write the target output.

Comment: If you want to access 'TopLink' as a string you can use "Object.keys" function.

Comment: Only TopLink text

Comment: Not TopLink array. Only text

Comment: You mean transform the data in the array to text?

Comment: answer mentioned below works.

Comment: so expected result is `TopLink`? @codeblogger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get your desired output: `Object.keys(MultiLinkArray[0])[0]`

```js
const MultiLinkArray = [
  {
    'TopLink': [
      {
        'name': 'BottomLink1',
        'to':'/bottomlink1'
      },
      {
        'name': 'BottomLink2',
        'to':'/bottomlink2'
      },
      {
        'name': 'BottomLink3',
        'to':'/bottomlink3'
      }
    ]
  }
]

console.log( Object.keys(MultiLinkArray[0])[0] );
```

This is because you have an array of objects, so you need to get your first object and then the first property in that object.

Comment: Note that you can also console.log(Object.keys(MultiLinkArray[0]).toString());